# insert integer in sorted doubly linked list

Tags: doubly-linked-list

Let S is a *sorted doubly linked list* of numbers and z is an integer. If I want to make a pseudocode to insert z so S will stay inserted, how would I go about this?

Is there any way to write an 'if' condition like:

if S[i] > z then insert z

or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Node node in list) {
    if (node.value > z.value) {
        z.previous = node.previous;
        z.next = node;
        node.previous.next = z;
        node.previous = z;        
    }
}
```